# M1 MacBook Air Base Model - How Much SSD Free Space exists on my 256 storage Mac?

Tags: macos, ssd, storage

I just got an M1 MacBook Air  base model with a 256GB SSD. After setting it up to my liking and running Migration Assistant and getting rid of junk I don't need, I wondered how much free space I had on the SSD.

- Stats menu bar items says 82% is used leaving 18% free or about 46GB free.
- Finder says 121.87 GB available.
- Disk Utility says 43.75 GB Free.
- System Settings > General > Storage says 122.7 GB.
- command line tool `df` also says 18% (46GB) available

I understand that they all might be looking at different things, so this is confusing to just about any person.

[image]

Which one is closest to being accurate?

[edit] Here are the results from Mints, mentioned in the answer:

```
Volume <Macintosh HD>:
    format APFS (NOT case sensitive)
    free space on </Volumes/Macintosh HD> is 42.65 GB of total 245.11 GB
    used space 202.45 GB
    available for important usage 159.98 GB
    available for opportunistic usage 30.3 GB
    sparse file storage available
    file cloning available
    volume supports compression.
```

Comment: 46 versus 43.75 GB is probably metric versus imperial gigabytes.  I don't know about the others.

Comment: Is "metric vs. imperial" a joke? I don't think either the metric or imperial measuring systems take stances on kB/KiB

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms probably a jokey way of saying gigabytes vs gibibytes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calculation of free space on APFS is apparently not so easy (see https://eclecticlight.co/2023/04/12/when-the-finders-error-exceeds-50/ for details).

> Over those years, the Finder has repeatedly shown errors in accounting for used and free space on APFS, although they’re seldom as large as this.
>
> Several of the valuable new features in APFS, like snapshots, sparse files and clones, make it difficult to arrive at a precise estimate of free space. However you do that, the figure is dynamic and has to make some assumptions. Although I don’t know how the Finder or Disk Utility make their estimates, [Mints](https://eclecticlight.co/mints-a-multifunction-utility/) uses a proven part of the API through URLResourceValues that’s readily accessible and correlates well with Disk Utility.

The results from DiskUtility or `df` are most likely more accurate than Finder.

Comment: This afternoon Stats reports that the SSD is only 39% full. Quite a change from yesterday's 82%. Have I deleted anything? No.

Comment: @Buadhai Stats may do even worse than Finder in handling APFS data structures.